# How to check Health of SOAP Based Web-Service built using Spring-WS-Core in spring boot

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot actuator provides health check such as Disk Space Health Indicator, Data Source Health Indicator and various other Health Indicators. But I don't find one for checking the health of SOAP based web service build with Spring-WS-Core.

I at least require a way to check whether WSDL are up and exposing the end point information with Spring-WS.